# Changing QGIS Layout names using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layouts

I am trying to append the date to the name of each layout in a project using Python as I can't see a way to do it in the graphical modeller which would be my normal weapon of choice. Eventually I want to update the date text but just adding it for now is fine.
So far I have the code below which mostly works except **layout.name** doesn't return the current display instead "<built-in method name of QgsPrintLayout object at 0x000001F178A590D0>" so I am clearly missing something. I have had a look in the cookbook and the API reference and the answer is probably there but I haven't found it.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
composerTitle = 'PrintLayout' # Name of the composer
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    layoutName = str(layout.name)+date
    layout.setName(layoutName)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was missing brackets after layout.name which should be layout.name() and doesn't need to be converted to a string.
The code below updates a text string on the end of a layout name.

```
from datetime import date 
today = date.today() # get date
date = today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y") # set and format text string
composerTitle = 'PrintLayout' # Name of the composer
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    oldname =layout.name()
    findleft = (len(oldname))-10 # find the legth of the layout name without the current date
    shortname = oldname[0:findleft] # layout name without the old date
    layoutName =shortname+date # layout name with new date
    layout.setName(layoutName)
```